# mysql security for working with arrays in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a a series of category ID's in an array, and they go into my query like:

```
 WHERE category IN(".implode(',',$categories))
```

Now for security purpose i would like to be sure each value from the array is actually an integer. Is there an easy way to do this, or should i break up my array, (int)$val each one, and then construct the array again?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: sow us full fragment of your php script

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's not possible to escape the whole 'in'-part of the query using the database. So you have two possibilities:

a) create a temporary table, insert and join to the original one. (May be preferred in cases where you don't have int's you want to have in the `where`-clause and you're working on very large datasets:

- Create a temporary table:`create temporary table yourTempTable (tempColumn varchar(42)) ENGINE=MEMORY;`
- insert all values using prepared statements to prevent SQL-Injections
- query your Database: `SELECT FROM orig_table INNER JOIN yourTempTable ON category = tempColumn`

b) technically, it's the solution you suggested: Modify the array before building the query. To make the code much more clearly readable, i'd suggest using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then simply modify your code:

```
WHERE category IN(".implode(',',array_map($categories, function($a){return (int)$a;} ) )
```

Here, you get a new array consisisting of all return-values from the [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) you supplied, which is in this case just a function which casts every value to an int. This array ist directly fed into `implode`, so you don't need any new variables, global functions, `for`-loops or anything else.